# Excel Hyperlink - using hyperlink base address

Tags: excel, function, hyperlink

I have been using the following hyperlink function to provide a link to a file based on the value of cell `B3` — the function is located in cell `L3` (and in `Bn` and `Ln`, as required).

```
=HYPERLINK(env("AGScan")&"\photos\"&B3&".jpg","photos\"&B3&".jpg")
```

As you can see this function uses the value of an Environment Variable called `AGSCAN` to provide the location of the file — in this case it would be `C:\Data\Catalog` — now using an environment variable is a bit restrictive — I would like to use the Hyperlink Base option instead since this is much easier to change and specify the file location in the hyperlink base in the Excel worksheet properties.

I can't seem to work out how to modify the above Hyperlink function to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Brett, While I was waiting and hoping for someone to respond I did some more experimenting and came up with this solution

=HYPERLINK(B2&".jpg","photos\"&B2&".jpg")

which differs slightly from yours. I decided to put the full path in the hyperlink base field, so I think I need to have the cell reference followed by the concatenation symbol and then the literal text. I guess a slightly better version of mine would be

=HYPERLINK(B2&".jpg",B2&".jpg")

Are your and my expressions equivalent?

Comment: No response from Brett, but of course, his expressions are not equivalent to yours since he forgot to leave the cell reference outside the quotes. If all the files you are linking to are in the _photos_ folder, either of your formulas would be fine. I guess the question would be whether the user needs to see that the file is in the _photos_ folder before clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set the hyperlink base in the worksheet properties, just use the relative path to get your photos to display. The hyperlink base path will automatically be prepended.

If you set your base path to "C:\Data\Catalog", use something like the following:

```
=HYPERLINK("photos\B3.jpg", "photos\B3.jpg")
```

If you set your base path to "C:\Data\Catalog\photos", use something like the following:

```
=HYPERLINK("B3.jpg", "B3.jpg")
```